# Access Violation Exception, when i call dll method

Tags: c#

How i can call function from dll? I Have `AccessViolationExeception`.

I have signature on C:

```
int WINAPI LogonNowait(Context* comm, 
              char*   host, 
              char*   username,
              char*   password,
              char*   shell_cmd,
              char*   logon_error_msg,
              int     buflen,
              SOCKET* sIO,
              SOCKET* sErr
              )

[DllImport(@"C:\\MyDLL.dll")]
        public static extern int WaitForLogon(ref Context ctx, ref string errmsg, int bLen, ref int sIO, ref int sErr);

 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CommContext
    {
        public uint inited;

        public uint rbufsize;
        public uint rbuf;
        public uint r_in_container;
        public uint left_in_container;
        public uint next_in_container;


        public uint wbufsize;
        public uint wbuf;
        public uint w_in_container;
        public uint first_free;
        public uint empty_container;

        public uint socket;
        public uint hdrtype;
        public uint last_error;
        public uint socket2;
        public string RX_context;
        public int port;
        public uint async_header;
        public string my_host_addr;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return port.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
How i can call this method from C# correctly?

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this.  Not sure if it is completely correct, but close. I updated original posting to get rid of errors occurring setting up the sockets.  You have to initialize CommContext before running code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
            //int WINAPI LogonNowait(Context* comm, 
            //  char*   host, 
            //  char*   username,
            //  char*   password,
            //  char*   shell_cmd,
            //  char*   logon_error_msg,
            //  int     buflen,
            //  SOCKET* sIO,
            //  SOCKET* sErr
            //  )
        [DllImport(@"C:\\MyDLL.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int WaitForLogon(IntPtr ctx, IntPtr host, IntPtr username, IntPtr password, IntPtr shell_cmd,  IntPtr errmsg, int bLen, IntPtr sIO, IntPtr sErr);

        [DllImport("ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Int32 WSAStartup(Int16 wVersionRequested, out WSAData wsaData);

        [DllImport("ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr socket(ADDRESS_FAMILIES_INT af, SOCKET_TYPE_INT socket_type, PROTOCOL_INT protocol);

        internal enum ADDRESS_FAMILIES_INT : int
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Unspecified [value = 0].
            /// </summary>
            AF_UNSPEC = 0,
            /// <summary>
            /// Local to host (pipes, portals) [value = 1].
            /// </summary>
            AF_UNIX = 1,
            /// <summary>
            /// Internetwork: UDP, TCP, etc [value = 2].
            /// </summary>
            AF_INET = 2,
            /// <summary>
            /// Arpanet imp addresses [value = 3].
            /// </summary>
            AF_IMPLINK = 3,
            /// <summary>
            /// Pup protocols: e.g. BSP [value = 4].
            /// </summary>
            AF_PUP = 4,
            /// <summary>
            /// Mit CHAOS protocols [value = 5].
            /// </summary>
            AF_CHAOS = 5,
            /// <summary>
            /// XEROX NS protocols [value = 6].
            /// </summary>
            AF_NS = 6,
            /// <summary>
            /// IPX protocols: IPX, SPX, etc [value = 6].
            /// </summary>
            AF_IPX = 6,
            /// <summary>
            /// ISO protocols [value = 7].
            /// </summary>
            AF_ISO = 7,
            /// <summary>
            /// OSI is ISO [value = 7].
            /// </summary>
            AF_OSI = 7,
            /// <summary>
            /// european computer manufacturers [value = 8].
            /// </summary>
            AF_ECMA = 8,
            /// <summary>
            /// datakit protocols [value = 9].
            /// </summary>
            AF_DATAKIT = 9,
            /// <summary>
            /// CCITT protocols, X.25 etc [value = 10].
            /// </summary>
            AF_CCITT = 10,
            /// <summary>
            /// IBM SNA [value = 11].
            /// </summary>
            AF_SNA = 11,
            /// <summary>
            /// DECnet [value = 12].
            /// </summary>
            AF_DECnet = 12,
            /// <summary>
            /// Direct data link interface [value = 13].
            /// </summary>
            AF_DLI = 13,
            /// <summary>
            /// LAT [value = 14].
            /// </summary>
            AF_LAT = 14,
            /// <summary>
            /// NSC Hyperchannel [value = 15].
            /// </summary>
            AF_HYLINK = 15,
            /// <summary>
            /// AppleTalk [value = 16].
            /// </summary>
            AF_APPLETALK = 16,
            /// <summary>
            /// NetBios-style addresses [value = 17].
            /// </summary>
            AF_NETBIOS = 17,
            /// <summary>
            /// VoiceView [value = 18].
            /// </summary>
            AF_VOICEVIEW = 18,
            /// <summary>
            /// Protocols from Firefox [value = 19].
            /// </summary>
            AF_FIREFOX = 19,
            /// <summary>
            /// Somebody is using this! [value = 20].
            /// </summary>
            AF_UNKNOWN1 = 20,
            /// <summary>
            /// Banyan [value = 21].
            /// </summary>
            AF_BAN = 21,
            /// <summary>
            /// Native ATM Services [value = 22].
            /// </summary>
            AF_ATM = 22,
            /// <summary>
            /// Internetwork Version 6 [value = 23].
            /// </summary>
            AF_INET6 = 23,
            /// <summary>
            /// Microsoft Wolfpack [value = 24].
            /// </summary>
            AF_CLUSTER = 24,
            /// <summary>
            /// IEEE 1284.4 WG AF [value = 25].
            /// </summary>
            AF_12844 = 25,
            /// <summary>
            /// IrDA [value = 26].
            /// </summary>
            AF_IRDA = 26,
            /// <summary>
            /// Network Designers OSI &amp; gateway enabled protocols [value = 28].
            /// </summary>
            AF_NETDES = 28,
            /// <summary>
            /// [value = 29].
            /// </summary>
            AF_TCNPROCESS = 29,
            /// <summary>
            /// [value = 30].
            /// </summary>
            AF_TCNMESSAGE = 30,
            /// <summary>
            /// [value = 31].
            /// </summary>
            AF_ICLFXBM = 31
        }

        internal enum SOCKET_TYPE_INT : int
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// stream socket 
            /// </summary>
            SOCK_STREAM = 1,

            /// <summary>
            /// datagram socket 
            /// </summary>
            SOCK_DGRAM = 2,

            /// <summary>
            /// raw-protocol interface 
            /// </summary>
            SOCK_RAW = 3,

            /// <summary>
            /// reliably-delivered message 
            /// </summary>
            SOCK_RDM = 4,

            /// <summary>
            /// sequenced packet stream 
            /// </summary>
            SOCK_SEQPACKET = 5
        }
        internal enum PROTOCOL_INT : int
        {
            //dummy for IP  
            IPPROTO_IP = 0,
            //control message protocol  
            IPPROTO_ICMP = 1,
            //internet group management protocol  
            IPPROTO_IGMP = 2,
            //gateway^2 (deprecated)  
            IPPROTO_GGP = 3,
            //tcp  
            IPPROTO_TCP = 6,
            //pup  
            IPPROTO_PUP = 12,
            //user datagram protocol  
            IPPROTO_UDP = 17,
            //xns idp  
            IPPROTO_IDP = 22,
            //IPv6  
            IPPROTO_IPV6 = 41,
            //UNOFFICIAL net disk proto  
            IPPROTO_ND = 77,

            IPPROTO_ICLFXBM = 78,
            //raw IP packet  
            IPPROTO_RAW = 255,

            IPPROTO_MAX = 256
        }

        // For 32-bit execution
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct WSAData
        {
            public Int16 version;
            public Int16 highVersion;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 257)]
            public String description;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 129)]
            public String systemStatus;

            public Int16 maxSockets;
            public Int16 maxUdpDg;
            public IntPtr vendorInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CommContext
        {
            public uint inited;

            public uint rbufsize;
            public uint rbuf;
            public uint r_in_container;
            public uint left_in_container;
            public uint next_in_container;


            public uint wbufsize;
            public uint wbuf;
            public uint w_in_container;
            public uint first_free;
            public uint empty_container;

            public uint socket;
            public uint hdrtype;
            public uint last_error;
            public uint socket2;
            public string RX_context;
            public int port;
            public uint async_header;
            public string my_host_addr;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return port.ToString();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CommContext cmt = new CommContext();
            IntPtr cmtPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(cmt));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(cmt, cmtPtr, true);

            string host = "LocalHost";
            byte[] hostBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(host + "\0");
            IntPtr hostPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(hostBytes.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(hostBytes, 0, hostPtr, hostBytes.Length);

            string username = "username";
            byte[] usernameBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + "\0");
            IntPtr usernamePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(usernameBytes.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(usernameBytes, 0, usernamePtr, usernameBytes.Length);

            string password = "password";
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password + "\0");
            IntPtr passwordPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(passwordBytes.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(passwordBytes, 0, passwordPtr, passwordBytes.Length);

            string shell_cmd = "shell_cmd";
            byte[] shell_cmdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(shell_cmd + "\0");
            IntPtr shell_cmdPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(shell_cmdBytes.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(shell_cmdBytes, 0, shell_cmdPtr, shell_cmdBytes.Length);

            const int BUF_LEN = 256;
            IntPtr errmsgPtr = new IntPtr(BUF_LEN);
            int bLen = BUF_LEN;

            WSAData data = new WSAData();
            WSAStartup(0x201, out data);

            IntPtr sio = socket(ADDRESS_FAMILIES_INT.AF_INET, SOCKET_TYPE_INT.SOCK_STREAM, PROTOCOL_INT.IPPROTO_TCP);

            IntPtr sErr = socket(ADDRESS_FAMILIES_INT.AF_INET, SOCKET_TYPE_INT.SOCK_STREAM, PROTOCOL_INT.IPPROTO_TCP);

            int results = WaitForLogon(cmtPtr, hostPtr, usernamePtr, passwordPtr, shell_cmdPtr, errmsgPtr, bLen, sio, sErr);

            string error = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(errmsgPtr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I developed this code my self using some structures found at pinvoke.net but the code wasn't at pinvoke.net.  I used 40 years of experience readng K & R "C-Language" many times as well as reading unix manual from cover to cover multiple times during lunch.  The main issue with the original code didn't use pointers to pass parameters, and did marshal the parameters to managed memory.  The user didn't specify type of socket to use so I used the ws2_32 socket and used pinvoke.net to guide me to the correct solution.  Pinvoke at some link references to msdn which I used also as reference.

Comment: I really have no idea what you're trying to tell me through that comment. All I asked for was for you to improve your answer.